# Why is my intended hyperlink being found in a different image?

Tags: html, css

I'm quite new to HTML/CSS and I've just started a new webpage. I'm trying to add a hyperlink to my image which is in my style sheet. However, when I've added the redirect url to my div element, the redirect is not appearing on the intended element, but the element adjacent to it. Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Here is my JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Syed213shah/bcnu8f21/1/

```
HTML:
<div class="item1"><a href="https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football"></a></div>

CSS:
.item1 { 


    background-image: url('https://pbs.twimg.com/media/D5gQCxCW0AE0skl.jpg');
    width: 100%;
    height: 200%;

}
```

Comment: you haven't closed the link - [please read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Comment: As @Pete said, you're missing the closing `</a>`. Although, this will most likely not solve your issue completely. Since the link wouldn't actually be clickable. What you probably should do is add the background to the `<a>` and just remove the whole `<div>`

Comment: @Pete do you mean adding </a> at the end? If so, when I add it at the end it becomes unresponsive

Comment: put something in it then or style it so it takes up some space - read the link in my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you do not close your link tag, so any content after it is clickable as link.

Also your link does not have any content and you do not set any dimensions for it, so it's width becomes 0 and you can't click on it.

Make your link as `item1`:

```
<a class="item1" href="https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football"></a>
```

Comment: you would also need to make it inline-block or block in order for it to take the dimensions for that class

Answer (score 1):

You placed the anchor tag inside the div, it's supposed to be the other way around. And you didn't close the anchor tag, that's why it's applying to the element next to it

Change `<div class="item1"><a href="https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football"></div>` to `<a href="https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football"><div class="item1"></div></a>`

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in your HTML.
You forgot to close the `<a>` element and also you need to take it outer of the `<div>`.

Here's the edited version:

```
<a href="https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football"><div class="item1"></div></a>
```